# Terminal cursor disappears when using Rails server and pry/byebug together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ruby-on-rails-4, pry

If I trigger `pry` or `byebug`, eventually while using the live-debug mode the cursor will disappear, and input will become slow/laggy. Ultimately I have to `Ctrl-C` and kill the unicorn/puma process. After I've quit the process the terminal works, but the cursor is sometimes still missing/invisible. Then I have to close the terminal and open another. I've tried two different servers (puma/unicorn) and two different debugging tools (pry and byebug).

Hard to say if this is related to the debug tool, the rails server or my Terminal. I'm using Terminal.app with Solarized theme.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the cursor disappears you can enter the command `stty echo` and hit enter. That should bring the cursor back.

Comment: Thanks but why is this necessary? Isn't this a bug?

Comment: what if I have rails server open and I can't quit it?

Comment: this didn't work for me at all